# delphi xe7 как сделал https запрос через ics

Tags: delphi

Работаю через компонент ICS, http работает, но запустить https не получилось, делаю как сказано в инструкции ставлю USE_SSL. Но не помогает. 
ошибка

```
[dcc32 Error] elsAPI.pas(42): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TSslHttpCli'
```

в примерах тоже все на http.

пример кода как объявляю

```
type
  THTTP = class(TSslHttpCli)  //    TSslHttpCli;
  // THTTP = class(THttpCli)  //    так работает! но только http
  private
  ...
  public
  ...
```

UPD 
компилировать удалось
сделал это http://prntscr.com/q9omju

но теперь ошибка http://prntscr.com/q9on3h 
как подключить / настроить контекст ?

UPD2

разобрался, надо подключить модуль OverbyteIcsWSocket

и инициализировать

```
  // SSL  включаем
  TSslHttpCli(self).SslContext := TSslContext.Create(nil);
  TSslHttpCli(self).SslContext.SslVerifyPeer := false;
  TSslHttpCli(self).SslContext.SslVersionMethod := sslV23_CLIENT;
  TSslHttpCli(self).SslContext.InitContext;
```

НО, опять ошибка!) теперь уже именно проблема в сетификатах.
если на сайте стоит сертификат letsencrypt то выдает ошибку хэндшейка... 
другие сайты получает...

как это побороть? 
я знаю что эта библиотека использует 2 DLL, может есть какие то новые версии?

UPD3

вобщем всем спасибки, все починил
нашел версию ssleay32.dll  1.0.1.7  (у меня была 1.0.1.6)

и все заработало

если что подключение загрузку dll библиотек делаю в коде проекта

```
  {$IFDEF USE_SSL}
  H1:= 0;
  H2:= 0;
  try
    H1:= LoadLibrary(PChar('LIBEAY32.DLL'));
    H2:= LoadLibrary(PChar('SSLEAY32.DLL'));
  except; end;
  try
    if H2 <> 0 then
      FreeLibrary(H2);
    if H1 <> 0 then
      FreeLibrary(H1);
  except; end;
  {$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Пробовали поискать где объявлен `TSslHttpCli` и добавить модуль с ним в uses?

Comment: он есть в том же модуле что и THttpCli
модуль OverbyteIcsHttpProt

Comment: там есть спец директива USE_SSL http://prntscr.com/q9afjl
но я ее выставил, в настройках модуля... и чет не помогло

Comment: *"ставлю USE_SSL"* - где и как? Очевидно, что если класс не найден, то вы сделали что-то не так и ваша директива не срабатывает.

Comment: делаю это тут http://prntscr.com/q9o97l  conditional defines

Comment: протестировал работу этих дефайнов простым кодом  {$IFDEF USE_SSL}
   ShowMessage('USE_SSL');
 {$ENDIF} - код работает, сообщение выдает

Comment: прокатило! компилируется, отписал проблему в вопросе

Comment: Похоже, что все ваши проблемы из-за того, что вы пользуетесь устаревшей версией ICS, т.к. актуальная версия [V8.63](http://wiki.overbyte.eu/wiki/index.php/ICS_Download) использует OpenSSL 1.1.1 (dll идут в комплекте) и директива `USE_SSL` включена по-умолчанию.

Comment: ок понял, скачаю новую